# How te remove the front wheel on a Merida misson cx400

Tags: front, through-axle

I need guidance on removing front wheel of my Merida cx400. I could not find any allen key or quick release provision.  Could you anyone please help me with tool set for the same.

Comment: Could you add a photo?

Comment: Do not see option here to add photo

Comment: There is an icon in the [edit] window for that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  If you can't add a photo, you should at least add a link to your bike (model and year) on the manufacturer website so that people can look up the specs for it.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the specs on [Merida Website](https://www.merida-bikes.com/en/bike/636/mission-cx-400) you have Fulchee through axles, FH1200 and FH1700.

Looking at these on the [Fulchee website](http://www.fulchee.com/en/product-226513/Through-Axle-for-E-Bike-Gravel-Road-MTB-etc-FH-1000-FH-1200.html) (for the front FH1200 at least) I see that the lever for releasing the thru-axle is integrated and needs to be pulled out for use, termed a hidden lever design apparently. You'll see a slotted piece instead of a hex key fitting, you need to pull this slotted piece out and it is the lever you need to use to unthread the thru-axle.

Unusual!

[image]

Comment: I bet my 5$ that the follow up photo/question will show that the lever is broken ...